# How to make a deep copy of a rectangular region of a cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv

Using opencv 2.3.  I have a region bounded by a rectangle that I want to extract and make a deep copy of, so that when that image is destroyed this rectangular region can live on.  I'm using this as a template for matching in a video sequence.  How can you do that?

Comment: Have you tried the `clone()` method? It copies the entire data of a `cv::mat`.

Comment: That's my initial approach, but I only want a subset of the cv::Mat cloned :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting [OpenCV 2.3 online documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) use this constructor to create rectangular region of interest of a cv::Mat:

```
// select a ROI
Mat roi(img, Rect(10,10,100,100));
```

and then to make a deep copy do:

```
Mat deepRoiExplorer=roi.clone();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Mat::clone()` to copy a ROI to a new image, or you can create the target image yourself and use `Mat::copyTo()`:

```
Mat source...;        // your source image
Rect sourceRect(...); // your ROI

// using clone
Mat target = source(sourceRect).clone();

// using copyTo
Mat target(sourceRect.size(), source.type());
source(sourceRect).copyTo(target);
```